# Ngrok redirecting to lvh.me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, ngrok

Awhile back, lvh.me was broken for me locally when running feature tests for rails. I solved the issue by editing a file locally that ensured lvh.me would point to localhsot:3000 - it was a solution I found after much googling, and now I cannot remember what file it was that I edited or what the solution was.

Enter a new problem: I'm trying to use ngrok to point to my localhost:3000 in order to test Amazon Connect integration, but ngrok consistently redirects to lvh.me instead - which, for my organization, points to our production site and database. Ngrok is pointing to Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040 and says it's forwarding to localhost:3000

Why is ngrok redirecting to lvh.me, and how do I fix this?

Comment: You ever fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the solution but I think file you was edited to ensure lvh.me pointed to localhost:3000 is located at `/etc/hosts`.